# migrate from local sqlite3 to mysql : django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table '' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, mysql, django

At the moment my app is working with a local database sqlite  db.sqlite3 my goal is to migrate (without losing data ) to a mysql database hosted in AWS. I follow the steps below, but  at step 3 I get the Programming Error: the table schema.tablename doesn't exist.

1. `python manage.py dumpdata > db.json`
2. Change the database settings to new database such as of MySQL.

```py
#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#    }
#}

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'guidemeto',
        'HOST':'----',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'dbmasteruser',
        'PASSWORD': '----',
    }
}
```

3. `python manage.py migrate`
4. `python manage.py shell`
5. Enter the following in the shell

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
```

6. `python manage.py loaddata db.json`

At step 3 I get the following error:

```
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
    MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist")

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    ...
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'new':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'guidemeto',
        'HOST':'----',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'dbmasteruser',
        'PASSWORD': '----',
    }
}
```

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate --database=new
3. python manage.py shell
   Enter the following in the shell

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
```

4. python manage.py loaddata db.json --database=new

and finally, the new database can be set as default.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but you're first changing the database in step 2, and then trying to delete tables from database that django is no longer connected to?

In any case if you're trying to just delete the sqllite DB along with the tables once you're done with import, you can just delete the local file and that should be it.

Comment: Many thanks  mesmerlord....I dont try to delete table.  I need to clarify my goal :
At the moment my app is working with a local database sqlite  db.sqlite3 my goal is to migrate (without losing data ) to a mysql database hosted in AWS. 
But  at step 3 I get the Programming Error: the table schema.tablename doesnt exist.

Comment: In that case (first create a backup, do this in the backup project), try deleting the files in your migrations folder in your apps except "__pycache__" folder and the __init__.py file.

Comment: I made it(deleted all migrations file but __init__ , I dont have any __pycache__ in migrations)...Then I switched to mysql  db setting and the first error I get is 'Unkown database guidemeto'... Then I create the db manually and I get the error described above 'Programming error: table doesnt exist'...

Comment: Have you done 'python manage.py makemigrations' and then 'python manage.py migrate' afterwards?